# fabricjs - loadFromJSON not respecting scaling

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

So what's happening is that when I load my data from JSON, the scaling of X and Y aren't respected so when the object loads, it maintains its original height/width. Any reason for this and anyway to work around it?

The left rectangle should be larger than the right.

```js
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

let json = {"objects":[{"type":"rect","originx":"left","originy":"top","left":323,"top":259,"width":50,"height":300,"fill":"#ff5b6d","stroke":null,"strokewidth":0,"strokedasharray":null,"strokelinecap":"butt","strokelinejoin":"miter","strokemiterlimit":10,"scalex":1.54,"scaley":1.54,"angle":0,"flipx":false,"flipy":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipto":null,"backgroundcolor":"","fillrule":"nonzero","globalcompositeoperation":"source-over","transformmatrix":null,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"rx":0,"ry":0},{"type":"rect","originx":"left","originy":"top","left":205,"top":198,"width":50,"height":300,"fill":"#ff5b6d","stroke":null,"strokewidth":1,"strokedasharray":null,"strokelinecap":"butt","strokelinejoin":"miter","strokemiterlimit":10,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"angle":0,"flipx":false,"flipy":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipto":null,"backgroundcolor":"","fillrule":"nonzero","globalcompositeoperation":"source-over","transformmatrix":null,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"rx":0,"ry":0}]}

canvas.loadFromJSON(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.18/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

let json = {"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":323,"top":259,"width":50,"height":300,"fill":"#ff5b6d","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1.54,"scaleY":1.54,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0},{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":205,"top":198,"width":50,"height":300,"fill":"#ff5b6d","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipy":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipto":null,"backgroundcolor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0}]}

canvas.loadFromJSON(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.18/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

fabricjs object property are in camel case. if you provide all with their proper key everything will work fine. I have changed your json data key to camel case. You can get all object property [here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html).

Comment: hmm i'll try with the camelcase. I'm also having issues with it being imported back in and not saving properly. I'm saving my data using `toJSON`. I'll muck around a bit first

Comment: I realised my issue, on the backend I was accidentally processing the text (making all characters lower-case). Fixed that and now it works as expected :)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you can manipulate each object as it's being built or something along that.

```js
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

let json = {"objects":[{"type":"rect","originx":"left","originy":"top","left":323,"top":259,"width":50,"height":300,"fill":"#ff5b6d","stroke":null,"strokewidth":0,"strokedasharray":null,"strokelinecap":"butt","strokelinejoin":"miter","strokemiterlimit":10,"scalex":1.54,"scaley":1.54,"angle":0,"flipx":false,"flipy":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipto":null,"backgroundcolor":"","fillrule":"nonzero","globalcompositeoperation":"source-over","transformmatrix":null,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"rx":0,"ry":0},{"type":"rect","originx":"left","originy":"top","left":205,"top":198,"width":50,"height":300,"fill":"#ff5b6d","stroke":null,"strokewidth":1,"strokedasharray":null,"strokelinecap":"butt","strokelinejoin":"miter","strokemiterlimit":10,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"angle":0,"flipx":false,"flipy":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipto":null,"backgroundcolor":"","fillrule":"nonzero","globalcompositeoperation":"source-over","transformmatrix":null,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"rx":0,"ry":0}]}

canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), (o, object) => {
                    object.scale(o.scalex, o.scaley);
                  });
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.18/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: can you explain how you got that canvas JSON data?? all the properties should be in camel case, but you have all in lower case. that's y its not working.